# Decoding string in PHP which is encoded in Python

Tags: php, python, utf-8, decode, encode

I want to decode a string in PHP, but the issue is the string which I need to decode in PHP is encoded in Python.
So how can I get the correct decoded string?

The string encoded in Python is putting into database from one end, and I need to get that encoded string and decode it in PHP with UTF-8.

Comment: And the string? What did you try?

Comment: In "what" was it encoded like JSON or what ?

Comment: A string contains whole "HTML file" is putting into database by encoding it to UTF-8 in python.
Now I am retrieving that string from database and want to decode it in php to UTF-8.
but I am getting some weird characters...
So How do I decode IT?

Comment: You mean you want to decode it _from_ UTF-8? You gotta watch out for that. We don't really need to know it came from python, but we do need an example of a few characters you're expecting to see and what you're seeing instead, or we won't have any idea what you've done wrong (there are lots of ways to get "weird characters").

Comment: "� You love to talk about cool technology.� Well, we have customers waiting to speak with you.�"
These question marks im seeing when I perform "utf8_decode" on that encoded string ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the database is configured to handle UTF8 encoded data correctly, you can return an ISO string with `utf8_decode()`; see http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php. That said I imagine the data is UTF8 for a reason so it's probably best to only decode just before trying to display it in an environment that doesn't support the encoding.

Comment: No, database is not configured to handle UTF8 encoding.